# Magento 2 how to get all cancel order collection

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

how to get cancel order collection in custom module ? like My Orders collection in customers dashboard (frontend). this collection how to get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to inject `\Magento\Customer\Model\Session` and `\Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory` class in your construct :

```
protected $_customerSession;
protected $_orderCollectionFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory
){
    $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
    $this->_orderCollectionFactory = $orderCollectionFactory;
}
```

Now, Add this below code in your function :

```
    $customerId = $this->_customerSession->getCustomerId()
    $ordersObj = $this->_orderCollectionFactory->create($customerId)->addFieldToSelect(
        '*'
    )->addFieldToFilter(
        'status',
        ['eq' => 'cancelled']
    )->setOrder(
        'created_at',
        'desc'
    );
    return $ordersObj;
```

Comment: sir, now I want all canceled order collection without customer id. is it possible??

Comment: Yes. Just remove argument from create().

Comment: Did you get collection now?

Comment: ok sir thank you .

Comment: sir can you help me i have i am in a big troble

Comment: which trouble???